# 18.04 LTS install

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

My system is running 16.04 LTS and has 2 separate solid state 120 gb drives; 'sda' and 'sdb'. My /system 'sda' needs to be re-partitioned (to remove windows, at the end) and the new 18.04 LTS installed. At the same time I need to keep my /home 'sdb' data and not have it erased during installation. I don't seem to see this capability with the 18.04 LTS installation options. Can someone inform me how I can do this. I want 'sda' to be totally comprised of ubuntu and 'sdb' remain as is. poopa

Comment: I see no problems. Install without formatting anything on sdb.

Comment: Thank you Pilot6, However this makes me wonder if the installation sw somehow looks to see if there is an '/etc/fstab' (my existing) or does it use / make its' own on a new full disc installation to 'sda' ??